# How to add a class to a link within a loaded HTML?

Tags: html, jquery

I had my site's navigation bar repeated in each page and I'm trying to make it easier for myself editing/adding pages in by taking the navigation and loading it into each page; so that when I want to add a new page I don't have to go through each and every html to add it in that way. Yet, when it has loaded in I want to be able to add a class to one of the elements inside of the navigation html to show that link as being selected (which is what the class itself is called).

I can get these to work independent of each other, but when it comes to getting them to work together, only the navigation loads in, but the element doesn't get the selected class. I assume this is because it can't see the loaded in navigation, but I'm not sure how I can get it to see it while still being able to set which link is 'selected' on the respective index.htmls for the corresponding pages.

This is what is in my page's html:

```
<head>
<!-- Other header stuff in here, but this is the JQuery I'm using. -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
$(function() {
  $("#nav-placeholder").load("/nav.html", function() {
    $(document.getElementById("roster").classList.add("selected"));
  });
});
</script>

<div id="nav-placeholder">
</div>
```

Replacing nav-placeholder with an html that is just cut and paste what the navigation used to be, per page, minus the 'selected' class on any of the links. All of the links have an id assigned, in this case I want the **roster** page to show as being selected.

Any help would be much appreciated!! I'm new to JQuery and usually just use it via trial and error or looking up specific uses but this one has me a bit stumped.

Comment: `$(document.getElementById("roster").classList.add("selected"));` should be either `document.getElementById("roster").classList.add("selected");` (vanilla JS) or `$("#roster").addClass("selected"));` (jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

$(document.getElementById("roster").classList.add("selected"))  should be just

document.getElementById("roster").classList.add("selected")